# How to get all the ids of elements inside a list using jquery

Tags: jquery

I've a list as

```
<ul id="list">
    <li id="one"></li>
    <li id="two"></li>
    <li id="three"></li>
    .....
    ....
    ....
</ul>
```

I want to get the `ids` of every `li` element inside the `ul#list`. Since the number of `li` item is unknown, I would want to go through a loop for as long as an `li` item exist. Something like

```
while($('#list li') exists){
     //Get id of the element
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
$('#list>li').each(function(){ alert($(this).attr('id')); })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through each list object like so:

```
$('#list li').each(function() {
});
```

And you can get the object's id from within the function like so:

```
$(this).attr("id");
```

Comment: Check your syntaxt you are missing a `'` after `li`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map` for this.

```
var IDs = $('li', '#list').map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

Comment: What will be the benefit of this over the others?

Comment: There's no difference except that `.map` returns you an array of the IDs as well as looping through them.